# Put buttons under each other that don't leave space when hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a Navigation field for my website, and I would like my buttons to be underneath each other with a white line in between. I have managed to get this part working by adding two line breaks next to the button, as seen here:

```
<button id = "next" onclick="next()">
    Volgende
</button><br><br>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have them show up like this, but if I hide the button, have the other buttons jump up, so they fill the gap and jump back down when the button becomes visible again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While you may have completely explained what you are looking for, it would be more useful to include an image or two showing the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to make it work.
Instead of using

```
document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = 'hidden'
```

I have now used

```
document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'none'
```

This makes the buttons fill the gaps when they're hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use line breaks for layout. That's a misuse of their purpose, which is to break *text*.

Just put your buttons in block-level (or inline-block level) containers, like divs. Obviously you'd hide and show the containers, not the buttons.

```css
.button-container:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="next-btn-container" class="button-container">
  <button id="next" onclick="next()">Volgende</button>
</div>

<div id="other-btn-container" class="button-container">
  <button id="other" onclick="next()">Volgende</button>
</div>

<div id="another-btn-container" class="button-container">
  <button id="another" onclick="next()">Volgende</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<br>` is not a good practice for cross-browser perspective, kindly use the  standard way by using `margin` and `display:block` property of css.

So your html will be like:

```
<button class="mb-20px d-block" id = "next" onclick="next()">
    Volgende
</button>
```

And add below line in your css

```
.mb-20px { margin-bottom: 20px; }
.d-block { display: block; }
```

Comment: You should put your code in a functioning snippet using the editor.

Comment: This works, but the buttons don't fill the gaps. Is there a way to do this?